# Ubuntu Crashes at Boot

Tags: boot, startup

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7 and was having trouble changing brightness. However, I found what was apparently a solution, it involved changing a directory I cannot remember sorry, however now Ubuntu crashes at the logo when starting up. I am unsure how to navigate recovery mode to get back and delete my changes, any help would be appreciated.

[Edit] Now when booting it only displays in text, Windows 7 boots fine however, just need to undo my error it seems but unsure how to navigate back to this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be best to boot using a LiveCD and then browse through to find what you had changed.

Remender that

```
gksudo nautilus
```

will get you to the file browser with root privileges so you can change any files

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply however I just booted from the CD, deleted the partitions and reinstalled it as it was kinda going crazy on me. All seems to be well now, just running update manager and drivers.

Comment: when your starting with a relatively fresh install that's often the fastest way to get things working properly -- glad you're back up and running

Comment: Indeed, installed it less than 24 hours ago after installing Mint on a friend's PC, led me to want to try something different with mine. Impressed so far, thanks for the help.